# Sticky in jquery tree menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tree, sticky

There is a dynamic tree menu in my application that is powered by jquery, and I am trying to implement a sticky.  All parent nodes in the tree are collapsed initially, and if a user opens a parent, then scrolls past the parent, I want the parent field to stick to the top of the menu until the user scrolls past the last child.  At which time, the parent would unstick.

Some children are also parents, too.  So there are many cases where I want multiple parents stuck at the top.  What I have works ok almost, but there is some weirdness.

The fields stick to the top and go away as expected when scrolling past the children.  But if two parents are open the second node does not unstick as it is suppose to; it just hangs out at the top no matter what.

I tried to debug with console.log, but whenever I write to the console, it throw a js exception "replace is not a member of undefined".

jquery, css, and html are below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

JQuery

```
  var _currentGenertion;
    var _loaded;
    var _initialTop;

    function ManageFieldListScroller() {
        $(".fields-list").scroll(function () {
            var divTop = $(".fields-list").position().top;
            var newTop = $('.field-item').position().top;
            if(newTop < _initialTop) {    
                stickParentFields(divTop)   //scroll up
            } else {
                restickParentFields(divTop) //scroll down
            }
             _initialTop = newTop;
        });
    }

    function restickParentFields(divTop) {
        $(".openedParent.unstuck").each(function () {
            var $nextParent = $(this);
            var top = $nextParent.position().top - 1; //"-1" because browsers are stupid
            var distanceToTopOfList = top - divTop
            var doIt = distanceToTopOfList <= 0

            $("div[path='" + $nextParent.attr('fieldid') + "']").each(function (i, item) {
                var $nextChild = $('#' + item.id);
                var nextChildTop = $nextChild.position().top
            var maxChildTop;
                if(i==0) {
                    minChildTop = nextChildTop;
                    maxChildTop = nextChildTop;
                } else {
                    if(nextChildTop < minChildTop) {
                        minChildTop = nextChildTop;
                    } else if(nextChildTop > maxChildTop) {
                        maxChildTop = nextChildTop;
                    } 
                }

                if (maxChildTop > divTop) {
                    _currentGenertion = _currentGenertion + 1;
                    var className = 'sticky' + _currentGenertion
                    $nextParent.removeClass('unstuck');
                    $nextParent.addClass('sticky');
                    $nextParent.addClass(className);
                }


            });
        });

        $(".openedParent.sticky").each(function () {  
            var $nextParent = $(this);
            var top = $nextParent.position().top - 1; //"-1" because browsers are stupid
            var distanceToTopOfList = top - divTop
            var doIt = distanceToTopOfList <= 0
            $("div[path='" + $nextParent.attr('fieldid') + "']").each(function (i, item) {
                var $nextChild = $('#' + item.id);
                var nextChildTop = $nextChild.position().top                  
                var minChildTop;
                if(i==0) {
                    minChildTop = nextChildTop;

                } else {
                    if(nextChildTop < minChildTop) {
                        minChildTop = nextChildTop;
                    } 
                }
                if (minChildTop > divTop) {
                    var parentClasses = $nextParent.attr('class')
                    var parentClassesArray = parentClasses.split(/\s+/)
                    $nextParent.addClass('unstuck');
                    $.each(parentClassesArray, function (i, css) {
                        var $currentClass = $(css)
                        if (css.indexOf('sticky') >= 0) {
                            $nextParent.removeClass(css);
                            Unstuck = true
                        }
                    });
                    if (Unstuck == true) {
                        _currentGenertion = _currentGenertion - 1;
                    }
                } 
            }); 
        });
    }


function stickParentFields(divTop) {
    $(".openedParent").not('.unstuck').each(function () {
        var $nextParent = $(this);
        var top = $nextParent.position().top - 1; //"-1" because browsers are stupid
        var distanceToTopOfList = top - divTop
        var doIt = distanceToTopOfList <= 0.5
        var className = 'sticky' + _currentGenertion;
        if (doIt) {
            stickParentField(className, divTop, $nextParent)

            var scrolledPastField = true;
            $("div[path='" + $nextParent.attr('fieldid') + "']").each(function (i, item) {
                var $nextChild = $('#' + item.id);
                var nextChildTop = $nextChild.position().top
                var topDifference = nextChildTop - top;
                if (nextChildTop > top) {
                    scrolledPastField = false;
                }
            });

            //  ------------------------------------------------ Unstick Fields ---------------------------------------------
            if (scrolledPastField == false) {
                //return false;
            }
            else {
                var parentClasses = $nextParent.attr('class')
                var parentClassesArray = parentClasses.split(/\s+/)
                $nextParent.addClass('unstuck');
                $.each(parentClassesArray, function (i, css) {
                    var $currentClass = $(css)
                    if (css.indexOf('sticky') >= 0) {
                        $nextParent.removeClass(css);
                    }
                });
                _currentGenertion = _currentGenertion - 1;
            }
        }
    });
}

function stickParentField(className, divTop, $nextParent) {
    var parentClasses = $nextParent.attr('class')
    if (parentClasses.indexOf(className) < 0) {
        var stickyDivCount;
        var nextClassName;
        var nextClassTop;
        className = 'sticky' + _currentGenertion
        stickyDivCount = $('.sticky').length
        _currentGenertion = stickyDivCount + 1
        nextClassName = 'sticky' + _currentGenertion
        nextClassTop = (stickyDivCount * 30) + divTop
        $("<style type='text/css'> ." + nextClassName + "{ top:" + nextClassTop + "px;} </style>").appendTo("head");
        var newUpperMargin = _currentGenertion * 20;
        var newHeight = $(".fields-list").height() - 20;
        $nextParent.addClass('sticky');
        $(".fields-list").css("margin-top", newUpperMargin);
        $(".fields-list").height(newHeight);
        $nextParent.removeClass('unstuck');
        $nextParent.addClass(nextClassName);
        $nextParent.css();
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (_loaded != true) {
            _loaded = true;
            _currentGenertion = 1;
            _initialTop = $('.field-item').position().top 
        }
        ManageFieldListScroller();
    });
```

CSS

```
.sticky {
    position:fixed;
}
.sticky1 {   
    /* 94.66 is the top of fields-list div, where we want sticky to start */     
    top:94.66px; 
}

.unstuck {
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML

```
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="divNinjaViewField" runat="server" objecttype="field" datatype='<%#Container.DataItem.DataType%>' haschildren='<%#If(Container.DataItem.HasChildren, True, False)%>' class='<%#If((Container.DataItem.IsSibling Or Container.DataItem.HasChildren) And (Container.DataItem.IsNumeric Or Container.DataItem.HasNumericChildren), "parentFieldItem nondrag isNumeric",
                                                                                                                                                                                                            If((Container.DataItem.IsSibling Or Container.DataItem.HasChildren), "parentFieldItem nondrag",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         If(Container.DataItem.IsNumeric Or Container.DataItem.HasNumericChildren, "field-item isNumeric",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "field-item")))%>'
                        style="margin-left: 0;" fieldid='<%# Container.DataItem.ID%>' path="" onclick="ParentDivClicked(this, true)" isnumeric='<%# Container.DataItem.IsNumeric %>'>
                        <div class="clearfix viewField" onmouseover="$(this).css('background-color', '#eee');" onmouseout="$(this).css('background-color', '');">
                            <span class='<%#If(Container.DataItem.HasChildren, "ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e", "icon-placeholder")%> <%#If(Container.DataItem.IsNumeric, "isNumeric", "")%>' style='float: left; margin-top: -2px; margin-right: .3em;'></span>
                            <%# Container.DataItem.FriendlyName%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <div id="divAdvancedOptions" onclick="AdvancedOptionsDivClicked(this, true)" class="advancedSourceOptions">
                        <div id="divAdvancedColumnOptions" runat="server" class="AdvancedOptions">
                            <div class="clearfix" style="color: #000; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; padding: 4px; margin-left: 12px;" onmouseover="$(this).css('background-color', '#eee');" onmouseout="$(this).css('background-color', '');">
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e advancedColumnOptions" style='float: left; margin-top: -2px; margin-right: .3em;'></span>
                                Advanced Column Options
                                <div class="specificAdvancedColumnOptions" style="display: none; font-weight: normal; padding: 4px; margin-left: 24px;">
                                    <div class="advancedOptionItem">
                                        <a id="calculatedFieldLink" href="#" onclick="toggleExpressionEditor(0, true);" class="db_link" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 200px;">Calculated Column</a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="advancedOptionItem">
                                        <a id="conditionalFieldLink" href="#" runat="server" onserverclick="conditionalFieldLink_ServerClick" class="db_link" style="width: 100%;">Conditional Column</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Your third code sample looks more like asp.net than classic asp - it can't be both.

Comment: It is asp.net.  The "classic asp" tag was an accident.